# How to watch variables in gdb?

Tags: debugging, variables, gdb

Is there any buffer in emacs' gdb that can print selected variables (e.g. `print *display`) on each change (step, next, finish etc.)?

It would be useful as opposed to typing print variable each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the manual, specifically [chapter 28.6.5.7 Watch Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Watch-Expressions.html) of the Emacs manual. Reproducing the first part of it here:

> If you want to see how a variable changes each time your program
> stops, move point into the variable name and click on the watch icon
> in the tool bar (gud-watch) or type C-x C-a C-w. If you specify a
> prefix argument, you can enter the variable name in the minibuffer.
>
> Each watch expression is displayed in the speedbar (see Speedbar
> Frames). Complex data types, such as arrays, structures and unions are
> represented in a tree format. Leaves and simple data types show the
> name of the expression and its value and, when the speedbar frame is
> selected, display the type as a tooltip. Higher levels show the name,
> type and address value for pointers and just the name and type
> otherwise. Root expressions also display the frame address as a
> tooltip to help identify the frame in which they were defined.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I've come across this page immediately after posting this question. Do you think this question should be removed? On the one hand like you said it's well-described in the manual, on the other hand I was struggling for two days with gud, before I realized that it's possible.

Comment: Meh. 90% of all questions on here can be answered by reading the manual, and they don’t get removed.